# How to Make My Web Page Stretch to Fit All Browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a website and it has as background a Video assets (mp4 file) and when I tested it I saw it in different way in Chrome/Explorer/Firefox, for it, I would need to add to my code to get to fit it in all browsers. My code is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<video width="1920" height="1080" controls autoplay loop= "loop">
  <source src="background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<script>   
$(function(){

var FancyPointer = function(){
  // A revealing module pattern, to create an
  // extensible pointer object.
  var pointerIcons = [], // Array of pointers.
      el, $el,           // element to listen to
      defaultImgSettings = {
          src: 'globe.gif',
          height: '30px',
          width: '30px',
          xPos: -15,
          yPos: -15
      };
  function startPointing(){

      $el.on("mousemove", function(e){
        var evt = e;
        $(pointerIcons).each(function(index, pointerEl){
          $(pointerEl.imgEl).clone()
            .css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'top':e.pageY+pointerEl.yPos,
                'left':e.pageX+pointerEl.xPos,
                'width': pointerEl.width,
                'height': pointerEl.height
            }).prependTo( $(document.body))
            .fadeOut(500, 'linear', function(){
                $(this).remove(); 
            });
        });

      });
  }

  function addPointer(options){
      var pointerEl = {};
      pointerEl.src = options.src || defaultImgSettings.src;
      pointerEl.height =options.height || defaultImgSettings.height;
      pointerEl.width = options.width || defaultImgSettings.width;
      pointerEl.xPos = options.xPos || defaultImgSettings.xPos;
      pointerEl.yPos = options.yPos || defaultImgSettings.yPos;

      pointerEl.imgEl = new Image();
      pointerEl.imgEl.src = pointerEl.src;
      $(pointerEl.imgEl).attr("height",  pointerEl.height)
        .attr("width",  pointerEl.width);

      pointerIcons.push(pointerEl);
  }

  function init(element){
    // the required option for the init should be the element in which we'll be listening.
    // If there is also an array included, the array should contain a number of options for
    //  the addPointer function. Otherwise, the user will need to manually call addPointer with
    //  each pointer to be added.
    el = element; // Save the original element
    $el = $(el);     // also create a jQuery-wrapped reference for later use.

    // Now here, we create an array, containing all the additional parameters after the first
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // Now, iterate over all these additional arguments. If we have any, assume them to be
    //  the options for addPointer (see above).

      if(args){
      $(args).each(function(index, pointerEl){
          addPointer(pointerEl);
      });
    }

    startPointing();

  }

  return {
    init: init,
    add: addPointer
  };
}(); 


FancyPointer.init("body",
{
      src: 'globe.gif',
      width: '80px',
      height: '80px',
      xPos: -40,
      yPos: -40
    }, 
    {
      src: 'smartphone.gif',
      width: '60px',
      height: '60px',
      xPos: 25,
      yPos: 25
    }, {
      src: 'monitor.gif',
      width: '50px',
      height: '50px',
      xPos: 30,
      yPos: -80
    },
    {
      src: 'tablet.gif',
      width: '55px',
      height: '55px',
      xPos: -85,
      yPos: -85
    },
    {
      src: 'laptop.gif',
      width: '50px',
      height: '50px',
      xPos: -80,
      yPos: 30
    },
    {
      src: 'chain.gif',
      width: '30px',
      height: '30px',
      xPos: -45,
      yPos: -50
    },
    {
      src: 'chain.gif',
      width: '30px',
      height: '30px',
      xPos: 15,
      yPos: 10
    },
    {
      src: 'chain1.gif',
      width: '30px',
      height: '30px',
      xPos: -45,
      yPos: 10
    },
    {
      src: 'chain1.gif',
      width: '30px',
      height: '30px',
      xPos: 25,
      yPos: -60
    });

   $("#addTrailer").on("click", function(){
        $(this).hide();
        FancyPointer.add({
          src: 'trail4.gif',
          width: '100px',
          height: '100px',
          xPos: -45,
          yPos: 25
        });
    })    
});
;</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anyboby help me with that?
Thanks in advance
Alejandro Castan
PS: Sorry for my little english....

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I wrote a while ago to make a `<video>` a full screen background:

```
// Resize the video elements so that we don't get any borders due to aspect ratio
function resizeVideo() {
  if ($(window).height() > $(window).width() * 0.5425) { // Which dimension is bigger dependant on aspect ratio (16:9)
    $("video").removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width").width("auto").height("100%");
  }
  else {
    $("video").removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width").width("100%").height("auto");
  }
};

// Add the resize function to the window resize event but put it on a short timer as to not call it too often
var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function () {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeVideo, 150);
});
```

Comment: Hi gvee,first thanks for your help. On the other hand, I added your code and it is not working yet. maybe I am making a mistake, for it, Could you add all the code complete(included the mine and the yours. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong ! You just have to  open a div and it is a block element, wicth means that it will take all the place available. Then you can use JS to scale elements like **video** and others that are in that main div to fit it. And it will work . :) You don't have to use JS for everiting :)

Comment: Hi voTkaPoweR, Please have me a little patience ! I am new in this topic !

Answer (score 0):

**Setting a video to a fixed width like 1920 is a really bad idea!**

You could use CSS to set the video to be 100% width and height so it becomes flexible, but then you could lose the aspect ratio and distort the video. So it's usually best to make the video fill the screen and have the edges get cut off if you're just using the video for a background and not concerned about subtitles and other video assets.

If you're going for the http://www.facebook.com/home effect, and want to size it proportionally for a masthead. You could do it like so:

```
var mastheadHeight,
    windowHeight = $(window).height(),
    windowWidth = $(window).width();

mastheadHeight = Math.min(Math.floor(windowWidth / 2), windowHeight - $('.menu').height() );
```

And then check this on browser resize as well to make it responsive. Note I've added a menu at the bottom of my masthead which is subtracted from the video height to allow it to be onscreen still!